# Websocket works in browser but hangs from other clients

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0, akka

We're using a WebSocket with Play Framework, and we're having a small issue with them.

When we connect to it from a browser console it works perfectly (I tried Chrome and Safari).

[image]

However, if we try connecting from other tools (like wscat or Gatling) we get the errors "socket hang up" or "Invalid Status Code 0" (those tools work fine with other websockets on the internet).

[image]

[image]

Looks like there are some problem with websocket handshake ...

We have tried with Play Framework 2.4.3 and 2.4.4. With this code in the controller:

```
  def socket() = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request => out =>
    Connection.props(out)
  }
```

Any idea of how to solve this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I used to test Gatling WebSocket support against Play's old chatroom sample, but I haven't updated sample from Play 2.2. If you could provide a full working sample project (eg pushed on github), I could check why Gatling fails to open the WebSocket.

Comment: Hi Stephane. I think that the problem is not about Gatling... it crashes with wscat and I test my Gatling code with http://www.websocket.org/echo.html and works fine...

Comment: Sure, but what I meant was that I could provide an analysis of what happens/lacks from the client point of view, which could help finding out what the issue is on the Play side.

Comment: And I'd also be curious about how browsers manage to open the WebSocket.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

Now it works. Play by default works in port 9000 and I had this port binded with php-fpm.... But I still don't understand why Play not crashes when trying to bind the application to an already binded port and why it worked consuming the WS from browser...

Thanks guys.